# What's wrong with my bezier curve?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I'm drawing a quadratic bezier curve, and I'm not sure why it's behaving the way that it is. It almost appears as if there's another control point influencing the curve, but there are only 3 control points, and the formula is only for quadratic curves.

Here are some images of what it's doing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zphds.jpg

And code:

```
Point Bezier::evaluate(float t)
{
    //  [x,y]=(1–t)^2*2P0+2(1–t)t*P1+t^2*P2

    Point P;
    P.x = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*points[0].x +
          2*(1 - t)*(1 - t)*t*points[1].x +
          t*t*points[2].x;

    P.y = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*points[0].y +
          2*(1 - t)*(1 - t)*t*points[1].y +
          t*t*points[2].y;

    return P;
}

void Bezier::drawCurve()
{
    glColor3d(red, green, blue);
    Point lastPoint = points[0];

    for (float t = 0.0; t <= 1.0; t += 0.01)
    {
        Point currentPoint = evaluate(t);
        drawLine(lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        lastPoint = currentPoint;
    }
}

void Bezier::drawHandles()
{
    glColor3d(red, green, blue);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        drawCircle(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].radius);
    }
}
```

Header

```
class Point
{
    public:
        float x;
        float y;
        float radius = 5;
};

class Bezier
{
    public:
        Bezier(float startX, float startY, float endX, float endY, float red, float green, float blue);
        Point evaluate(float time);
        void drawCurve();
        void drawHandles();

        Point points[3];

        float red;
        float green;
        float blue;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula you're using is wrong

```
P.x = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*points[0].x +
      2*(1 - t)*t*points[1].x +
      t*t*points[2].x;

P.y = (1 - t)*(1 - t)*points[0].y +
      2*(1 - t)*t*points[1].y +
      t*t*points[2].y;
```

You have an extra `(1-t)` in the second term.

Comment: agh I figured it was in the formula and read over it 3 times before posting just to be sure. Somehow that slipped by. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! This happens all the time.